# Unable to close a pop up using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So here is my code so far that isn't faring to well:

```
url = 'https://americanbarbell.com/products/american-barbell-cast-kettlebell'
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\msedgedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(path)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="closeIconSvg"]').click()
```

But I keep getting this back:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="closeIconSvg"]"}
```

I'm not seeing anything about an iFrame? I saw a lot of other people with this problem but have yet to find a working solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the modal window and wait until it loads.

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="attentive_creative"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
status_message = wait.until(
      EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#closeIconContainer"))
driver.find_element(By.ID, "closeIconContainer").click()

)
```

You will need to import a couple of methods.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

A super simple work around ended up being

```
driver.refresh()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pls, show line where this id is

and probably you may use such solution:

```
url = 'https://americanbarbell.com/products/american-barbell-cast-kettlebell'
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\msedgedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(path)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

try:
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="closeIconSvg"]')
    element.click()
except NoSuchElementException:  # Error catch here
   print('Error.')
```